# Add css to last element

Tags: html, css

I have bootstrap based menu and I want to add css to last dropdown menu. So I have html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
        <li class="drop">
            <a href="1.html">Lorem</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="drop">
            <a href="1.html">Lorem</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I try to add css:

```
 .navbar-nav li.drop ul.dropdown:last-of-type{
    left:-140px;
  }
```

But this code add css to all dropdown submenu, but I want only last

Comment: `.navbar-nav li.drop:last-of-type ul.dropdown:last-of-type` should be it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `last-of-type` is looking for the last sibling, but your two `.dropdowns` are not siblings - they are children of the `.drop` elements.

If you do this instead :

```
.navbar-nav li.drop:last-of-type ul.dropdown{
    left:-140px;
}
```

... then it should work as you expect.